# Grouping data into 5 minute intervals within a time range

Tags: mysql, database-design, group-by, chart

I am trying to prepare data for a candle stick chart. I have some records on MySQL database as shown below:

```
| Rate     | Date                |
|----------|---------------------|
| 0.001111 | 2017-11-12 19:13:05 |
| 0.001214 | 2017-11-12 19:14:11 |
| 0.001612 | 2017-11-12 19:15:42 |
| 0.001231 | 2017-11-12 19:16:23 |
| 0.001514 | 2017-11-12 19:17:23 |
| 0.001611 | 2017-11-12 19:26:33 |
| 0.001421 | 2017-11-12 19:27:25 |
| 0.001214 | 2017-11-12 19:28:27 |
| 0.001611 | 2017-11-12 19:29:55 |
|----------|---------------------|
```

I want to group below data as shown below:

```
| Rate     | Date                |
|----------|---------------------|
| 0.002325 | 2017-11-12 19:10:00 |
| 0.004357 | 2017-11-12 19:15:00 |
| 0.004357 | 2017-11-12 19:20:00 |  # Auto generated record of missing record.
| 0.005857 | 2017-11-12 19:25:00 |
|----------|---------------------|
```

I was trying to understand calendar table, but I wasn't able to do with that.

I also followed this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range but still failed.

UPDATE:

This is my sample query that I am using currently to get data with date sorting and grouping.

```
SELECT 
SUM(exchange_rat) AS totalAmount, 
DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(created_at) - unix_timestamp(created_at) mod 300), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') as createdAt 
from payments group by createdAt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had MariaDB, you could use a "sequence" table for auto-generating the dates.

I prefer to do something like this *before* `JOINing` to `calendar`:

```
SELECT
        FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date) / (5*60))
                      * (5*60)) AS chunk_start,
        SUM(...)
    ...
    GROUP BY chunk_start
```

That does the arithmetic earlier in the process, hence is somewhat faster.

Comment: I am using MySQL database and i updated my query sample on my question, i think i have that syntax that you gave me but i still miss that gaps for missing dates.

Comment: The technique is to `RIGHT JOIN` to a table that has all the dates, including missing days.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic implementation of a calendar table. As you cans see, it simply group dates using intervals.

```
drop table if exists calendar;
drop table if exists intrv;

create table calendar(id int, dt timestamp);

insert into calendar values 
(1, '2017-11-12 19:10:00'), 
(1, '2017-11-12 19:15:00'),
(1, '2017-11-12 19:20:00'),
(1, '2017-11-12 19:25:00'),
(1, '2017-11-12 19:30:00');

create table intrv (Rate decimal(18,6), Dt timestamp);

insert into intrv values
(0.001111, '2017-11-12 19:13:05'),
(0.001214, '2017-11-12 19:14:11'),
(0.001612, '2017-11-12 19:15:42'),
(0.001231, '2017-11-12 19:16:23'),
(0.001514, '2017-11-12 19:17:23'),
(0.001611, '2017-11-12 19:26:33'),
(0.001421, '2017-11-12 19:27:25'),
(0.001214, '2017-11-12 19:28:27'),
(0.001611, '2017-11-12 19:29:55');

select    c.dt as dt1,
          sum(i.Rate) 
from      calendar c
left join intrv i
on        i.dt >= c.dt 
and       i.dt < date_add(c.dt, interval 5 minute)
group by  c.dt;
```

```
| dt1                 | rate     |
|---------------------|----------|
| 12.11.2017 19:10:00 | 0,002325 |
| 12.11.2017 19:15:00 | 0,004357 |
| 12.11.2017 19:20:00 | NULL     |
| 12.11.2017 19:25:00 | 0,005857 |
| 12.11.2017 19:30:00 | NULL     |
```

*rextester [here](http://rextester.com/VFV64537)*

For the second part of the question, you should explain how to auto-generate the desired values.

Comment: I tried this but i am confused to know that how new dates will be available there on future? i mean i will need all future time for left join right?

Comment: Yes you should generate new dates. Googling a bit you can easily find scripts to generate calendar tables or to generate table values between two dates.

Answer (score 0):

This is my method. Flatten the data by doing an integer divide, then multiply to get into 5 minute segments

```
select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, '1900-01-01',   p.[date])/5*5, 0), SUM(p.rate)
from payments p
group by dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, '1900-01-01',  p.[date])/5*5, 0) 
order by 1
```